# Assigning dynamic value to the receive activity properties

Tags: c#-4.0, workflow-foundation, workflow-foundation-4, workflowservice

I am writing a custom activity using imperative code.  In my compsoition, I have Receive activity as a one of the composed activity.  In that activity, I want to set ServiceContractName and OperationName property dynamically, meaning, when developer who is consuming my custom activity have to set.  So I declared one property and one InArgument for this purpose.  I assign this property and Argument value to the local (sequence varriable).  When I try to assign these varriables to Receive activity properties, I am getting compile time error.  How to assign a Varriable to string and XName properties of Receive activity.

```
return new Sequence
{
    Variables = { operationName, serviceContractName},
    Activities = 
    {
        new Assign<string>
        {
            To = new OutArgument<string>(serviceContractName),
            Value = new InArgument<string>(ctx => ServiceContractName.Get(ctx))
        },

        new Assign<string>
        {
            To = new OutArgument<string>(operationName),
            Value = new InArgument<string>(ctx => OperationName)
        },

        new Receive
            {
                ServiceContractName = serviceContractName,
                OperationName = operationName,
                CanCreateInstance = true,
                Content = new ReceiveMessageContent
                {
                    Message = new OutArgument<Request>(request)
                }
            }
        },
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do that. The ServiceContractName and the OperationName are not InArguments but normal properties and they have to be set at design time, not at run time.